# Why The Images On My Site Do Not Resize Correctly?

Tags: html, css

On my site [ [https://gatecybertech.com](https://gatecybertech.com/) ] why the images aren't re-sizing correctly ?

(1) The first place is "GATE_Frame_1" and "GATE_Frame_2", at line # 67,68, I have to use the following to make them appear the same size :

```
  #GATE_Frame_1 { width: 78%; height: auto; }
  #GATE_Frame_2 { width: 98%; height: auto; }
```

The png files of those images are of the same size, and yet if I don't use the above 2 lines, on my mobile phone, when the site is shown, the images won't re-size and there will be some white space on the right side [ [How To Get Rid Of White Space In Html Page Viewed From Android Phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60894536/how-to-get-rid-of-white-space-in-html-page-viewed-from-android-phone) ], but why do I have to set the width differently [ 78% and 98% ] to make them appear the same size, it's working properly, I just don't understand why it is behaving like this.

(2) At Line # 78,79, I have to use the following lines to make the images appear similar size :

```
  #Traditional_vs_GATE_1 { width: 96%; height: auto; }
  #Traditional_vs_GATE_2 { width: 99.6%; height: auto; }
```

This is the best I could do, I've tried multiple different combinations, this is the best match, but not 100% the same size, as you can see, if you mouse over them [ last big image on the web site at the bottom ], it will re-size just a few pixels, but in the case of the first image [ GATE_Frame_1 / GATE_Frame_2 ], when you mouse over them, they are the same size. I figured it must be the width to height ratio of the images that caused the problem, if the bottom image has the same w/h ratio as the top image, the problem will be gone, so I added some white space to the bottom of the Traditional_vs_GATE images, so the w/h ratio is the same as the top image, but the problem still exists, so my question is what's a good solution to fix the Traditional_vs_GATE_1 & Traditional_vs_GATE_2 images, so that when I mouse over them, they will show the same size ?

I know if I get rid of the 2 lines [ # 78,79 ] this will work like the way I want it to be, but then the site won't display properly on the mobile phone's browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From @Ru NE's answer I got inspiration, I fixed the bottom image, so now it's showing the same size when mouse over it with the following change :

```
  .pic-container-2 .pic-hover{position:absolute; top:0px; left:18px; display:none;}
  .pic-container-2:hover .pic-hover{display:block;}

  #Traditional_vs_GATE_1 { width: 96%; height: auto; }
  #Traditional_vs_GATE_2 { width: 99.5%; height: auto; }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first place you can give #GATE_Frame_2 the same width of 78% and for the parental div remove left: 104px. For the second the same. Gove both images the same size and remove left from css for the parental div of the hover image

```
.pic-container-2 .pic-hover {left: 0;}
#Traditional_vs_GATE_2 {width: 96%;}
#Traditional_vs_GATE_ {width: 96%;}

.pic-container-1 .pic-hover {left: 0;}
#Traditional_vs_GATE_2 {width: 78%;}
#Traditional_vs_GATE_1 {width: 78%;}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, didn't work for either image, but it gave me inspiration to fix the 2nd image, now it's working, though still using different sizes, don't know why, but I'm happy it's now working properly.